# What is the best strategy to broadcast 500K push notifications at once via AWS SNS mobile push minimum latency?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, push-notification, amazon-sns

It seems we can not subscribe more than 10K subscriptions per sns topic.

To achieve minimum latency from send to notification received in the device, would it be recommended 
* to create 50 topics containing  10K users each ? this would then result in 50 sns publishes which is easy to manage in the sender side (has any used this scenario in production ? ). 
or 
* to do 500K direct sns publishes  (which will involes having some infrastructure (+ associated cost) to be able to parallelize such a big number sns publishes in a short amount of time)

thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything for solving your issue? I have the same question and am trying to create several topics with 10K users each.

Comment: hi nano , i have not found anything useful yet.

Comment: I'm currently using topics for adding 10K users each time and it works pretty good.

Comment: seb + @nano -- How are you handling subscription confirmation in your iOS app? This has me stumped...

Comment: @ericpeters0n I've a single topic in AWS-SNS and I'm adding the mobile subscribers to this topic. The topic has thousand of subscribers. Sending one message to this Topic sends the message to all its subscribers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amazon SNS now allows topics with 10 million subscriptions. If you intend to deliver the same message to all subscribers, use a topic to broadcast. If you need to customize the message for each subscriber, you should use Direct Publish.

Comment: Is there an easy way to create a topic on the fly before sending the notification ?